# Approximation to the negative-binomial and negative-hypergeometric distributions

Tags: probability, approximation, binomial-distribution

It is known that [a binomial distribution can be approximated by a normal variable with the same mean and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation), for sufficiently large $n$.

What approximations are known for the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Definition) (the number of successes before the $r$-th failure in draws with replacements) and for the [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution) (the same without replacements), for sufficiently large $r$?

Note: I am mainly interested in assymetric scenarios, in which the total number of successes is much smaller than the total number of failures.

Comment: You can get a normal approximation as well. For what purpose do you need the approximation?

Comment: I need the approximation in order to make a claim such as: "The probability of $f(k)$ successes is $O(1/k)$, and thus it goes to 0 when $k$ goes to $\infty$". $f(k)$ is a certain function of $k$ which I have to define. I find it easier to make such statements when working with normal variables.

Comment: Normal approximation to hypergeometric may be OK for this purpose, if symmetrical (urn has equal numbers of red and white balls). Be careful using normal approximations to skewed discrete distributions--for some purposes the fit in the tails is not good enough.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I am mainly interested in assymetric scenarios, in which the total number of successes is much smaller than the total number of failures. Are there known approximations for this case?

Comment: Rapidly getting above my pay grade in asymptotics here. But since no one else is giving brighter ideas, I'll mention an interesting article on 'Prototype' doing approx. negative binomial with gamma. URL is humongous, but got with Google using obvious key words.